# terminal command break apart the functionality

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix, grep

I know a command that I use pretty often when working on someone else's code base, here is an example

```
find ./ -name "*.php" | xargs grep "my_awesome_function("
```

I have already read through the docs on each of the commands here as `find`, `pipe`, `xargs` and `grep` from 
http://www.computerhope.com/unix.htm

Yet I still don't entirely understand how this command searches for every php file from current directory down and then looks for which of them contain a string "my_awesome_function(". I understand how pre pipe part works, but after the pipe my understanding vanishes. I get that each file is sent like an argument to the grep command, can someone explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try executing the `find` command without the last part:

```
find ./ -name "*.php"
```

What you'll see is a list of filenames, all ending with `.php`.

Now the `xarg` commands reads all these filenames from the pipe, takes a bunch of them (you can set how many using option `-n 2`), and then calls its argument with these names. So if the output of find is `file1.php file2.php file3.php`, and `xarg` would group at most two files together (or you force it to with `xargs -n 2`), then it would call

```
grep "my_awesome_function(" file1.php file2.php
grep "my_awesome_function(" file3.php
```

which in turn produces your output.
You can see what is really going on by inserting an `echo`:

```
find ./ -name "*.php" | xargs echo grep "my_awesome_function("
```

Also play around with the grouping:

```
find ./ -name "*.php" | xargs -n 2 echo grep "my_awesome_function("
```